# How does redefining equality actually work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, equality

As a novice, I've pored through a multitude of guides on how to redefine equality, but none of them actually explains HOW it works, just what to write.

So, a code that looks like this,

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def ==(whatever)
    self.name == whatever.name
  end
end
```

will consider

```
name1 = Person.new("Jack")
```

and

```
name2 = Person.new("Jack")
```

equal, whereas the old `==` method didn't because it compared something else.

However, how does it actually work? What is "whatever" (many seem to write "other") and what does it do? Edit: To clarify, I understand the point OF doing it, I just don't understand the inner workings. What happens, step by step? What does whatever.name do and why? How does returning a true/false value in the == method help redefine it? Those are the kind of questions that I'm asking here.

Comment: I think your doubt is more about the default behavior of `==` method. What it does is comparing the object_id of the two objects. Basically it's telling you if they ARE the same instead of LOOK the same. Another thing: `==` is a method like any other, it will use as argument whatever you put in front of it. You could call it like so: `name1.==(name2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

```
name1 = Person.new("Jack")
```

and

```
name2 = Person.new("Jack")
```

When you do:

```
name1 == name2
```

What actually happens is that you call the redefined `==` method on your `name1` object and pass the `name2` object as an argument. In other words:

```
name1.==(name2)
```

In the definition of `==` the argument is called `whatever`. So `whatever` is actually `name2`.

A simple example to illustrate the above point:

```
def foo(bar)
  puts bar
end

a = 'b'

foo(a) #=> "b"
```

So you pass `a` to the `foo` method, but the argument is called `bar`. So, inside the `foo` method you use `bar`, not `a`.

The same goes for the example above. In the `==` method you use `whatever`, not `name2`.

Comment: Yeah, I finally get it. I felt I was smoking something when you used such a beginner's example to demonstrate arguments (which I of course know how they work) and I still couldn't figure things out.  I get it now, I think, so thanks. The only thing still tripping me up is how we can actually use == inside the == method which redefined it. It's circular and it messes with my brain.

Comment: @LyndonJohnson the `==` from the Person class is not the `==` from the String class.

Answer (score 1):

> What is "whatever"

When you call:

```
name1 == name2
```

Ruby "translates" this internally to a function call to:

```
name1.==(name2)
```

`==` in this function call has no "special" meaning, it's just the 
function name (just as `foo` or `do_something` might be a function name).

As you can see, `whatever` is the argument that gets passed to the function, which is the right-hand side of `==`.

This is called "operator overloading"; it means an operator can do something different depending on the variables; you can do this with all operators, such as `>` (greater than), `=` (assignment), etc.

[Here's a page page that deals with operator overloading in some more depth](http://ruby.about.com/od/oo/ss/Overloading-Operators.htm).

> Why does there need to be self.name and not just name or @name?

All are valid; in this case, `name`, `self.name`, and `@name` refer to the same variable. Some people just prefer writing `self.name`, I am one of those, and it's more explicit that you're referring to an instance variable, rather than a local variable in a function (less "magic"). I also have a long Python background, where the `self` is mandatory, so I'm used to it.
Writing just `name` seems to be more common in Ruby, though.

> whereas the old == method didn't because it compared something else.

From [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F) (emphasis mine):

> At the Object level, **== returns true only if obj and other
>   are the same object**. Typically, this method is overridden in
>   descendant classes to provide class-specific meaning.

So in your case, `name1` and `name2` are obviously not the same object, even though the have the same *value*.
Ruby has no way of knowing what you consider to be the *value* of `Person`, so you need to overwrite the `==` operator to tell Ruby when *you* consider two objects to be the same.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I don't really understand why you started talking about operator overloading. Though quite interesting, I fail to see the relevancy.

Comment: @LyndonJohnson Because what you are doing, is overloading the `==` operator. A page to explain the concept in slightly more depth: http://ruby.about.com/od/oo/ss/Overloading-Operators.htm

Answer (score 1):

Using your own example:

```
Person.new("Jack") == Person.new("Jack")
```

What is being compared here is the object as a whole, which will have differing `object_id`s.  This will cause the equality comparison to fail.

By overriding `==`, you are causing the comparison to look at something that actually matters to you, in this case, the `name` attribute.  So what you pass in the second `Person` object to evaluate equality, it is actually looking at the `name` attribute, not the object as a whole, as is done before you override `==`.  To answer your question, you can use `name` or `@name` in the comparison, it doesn't matter.  `self` just refers to the object on the left side of the equation, `whatever` is the object on the right.

Comment: Not at all what I asked. Read the question again.

Comment: I disagree, but being beligerent on this site isn't really how we roll. Especially to more than one person.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question. In your first "edition" you just wrote the same thing I did. Then you added something helpful about self, which I appreciate, but it still doesn't answer the main question.

Answer (score 1):

**The title of the OP asks "How does redefining equality actually work in Ruby?". The generic answer is:**

Ruby has a few methods that can be considered "equality": `#==`, `#equal?`, `#eql?`, `#===`, and all of them have their specific mission slightly different from others. Behind the scenes, operator methods such as `#==` work as follows:

```
42 == 42
```

gets translated into

```
42.==( 42 )
```

that is, message `:==, 42` gets sent to the number `42`:

```
42.send( :==, 42 )
```

When you redefine `#==` method on any object, this redefined method handles the message.

While other answers mentioned what `Object#==` does, you can note that for comparable objects (ie. the ones to which you can add mixin `Comparable`), you should redefine method `#<=>`, and the mixin will handle `#==` (as well as `#<` and `#>` and a bunch of other methods) by itself.

**Furthermore, the OP asks minor syntactic questions:** What is `whatever`, and whether `self.name` is necessary. These are not related to equality method at all.

`self.name` is not necessary, because `self` is always the implicit receiver. Instead of `self.name == whatever.name`, it is possible to write just `name == whatever.name`. Overuse of explicit `self` can be considered a pythonism. `@name` cannot be used, because it means something else (reference to an instance variable).

In method definition

```
def ==( whatever )
  name == whatever.name
end
```

`whatever` is a parameter. The method is being defined with a single parameter `whatever`. When the method is called, it will thus require a single argument, which it will assign to a local variable `whatever`. This is just method definition syntax, nothing else.

**All in all**, the version of `#==` the OP asks about compares objects of `Person` class by their names, and considers them equal if their names are equal, even though they are not the same objects.

Comment: Is this really an answer to what I asked?

Comment: Nope, this is a shotgun answer, hoping to answer also the things the OP doesn't ask explicitly.

Comment: In fact, your title asks different question than your text. No, `self.name == whatever.name` is not necessary, `name == whatever.name` is enough. But this has nothing to do with equality =).

Comment: No, it doesn't. The self thing is just a bonus question. Still waiting for the answer how redefining the == method works.

Comment: More than 1 person has answered that question for you.  It seems you aren't getting the answer you want, as opposed to the answer that is correct.

Comment: I'm just getting back what I wrote myself. No one has answered what whatever.name actually DOES.

Comment: Just "method definition syntax" you say, but I still don't understand what it does, which was my main question here. I'm sorry for the other question (singular) regarding self, I thought I could sneak it in with no harm done.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answers below:

1. However, how does it actually work?

When you write **name1 == name2**, you actually send the name2 variable to the instance method 
**==(whatever)**

2. What is "whatever" (many seem to write "other") and what does it do?

Is the name of the parameter you pass into the method **==**, because Ruby does not require you to specify the type of the parameter, and everything is an object, so you can pass anything to the == method. That's why it was written "whatever", you can name whatever you want.

3. Why does there need to be self.name and not just name or @name?

inside the == method, self is the current instance so when you write name1 == name2, then **self** is **name1**. Using self.name is identical to use **@name**. If you just write **name**, which has not been defined before, therefore its value will be **nil**. Which will make the comparison become **nil == whatever.name**. This is probably not what you want.

EDIT:
**What does whatever.name do**

In short, it gets the value of a property called "name" from the whatever object.

In details, Ruby will ask the "whatever" object, if it can respond to the "name" message. If yes, the value will be returned, if not an exception will be raised. In the comparison scenario you gave, apparently name2 instance responds to the "name" message, because you defined an attribute reader **attr_reader :name** in the Person class.

You can pass any object as a parameter to the == method as long as it responds to the "name" message, so "whatever" doesn't have to be  Person instance.

Comment: I named it "whatever" for that reason, yes. But I still don't get how it works. What does whatever.name do? Also, name has been defined just like @name has. In fact, they're the same.

Comment: I feel this is the best answer, but it just doesn't click for me. That might be my fault, though. "self.name == whatever.name" returns either true or false, correct? How does that help the method do/change anything? What value does whatever.name return and why? Those two questions are what I feel haven't been answered. Am I being stupid here, missing the answer, or am I correct in that they haven't been explicitly answered?

Comment: @LyndonJohnson `whatever` is just the object you pass into the `==` method. In your example you pass in the `name2` object, see: `name1.==(name2)`. So `whatever.name` returns the same as `name2.name`, namely: `"Jack"`.

Comment: @LyndonJohnson, accept it. Click the "accept". `self.name` returns the name of `self`, the object on which the method is called. `whatever.name` returns the name of the argument, ie. the object with which the receiver is being compared. And the result of the comparison of their names, be it true or false, is returned as the result of the `Person#==` method.